# Set the value of a parameter in a Series expression

Tags: replacement, series-expansion

I have a lengthy expression resulting from a series expansion in some dummy variable $e$ which I now wish to set equal to 1. However, when I try to use a `ReplaceAll` $/.e\rightarrow1$, it traces back to the series expansion in which the variable $e$ was first used and returns an error.

How do I get Mathematica to interpret the function at face-value so I can sub out the variable as if I had just typed in the expression by hand?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! For your further questions, please include a minimal working example of the code you are using so that others can reproduce your problem and more easily provide a concrete solution :) Since you've found your solution (which is also kind of a trivial "mistake"), but didn't provide any concrete code, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: As you already learned, Normal will convert a SeriesData object to a “normal” expression. Sometimes questions like this get closed since it is, after all, reasonably well documented. But people do get bitten by this particular one, so I hope this either gets retained, or is removed only if there is a prior duplicate.

Comment: Thanks both. Indeed this turned out to be fairly trivial, but such things can easily be missed when one is self-taught in Mathematica. A Google search of the above didn't turn up much, so hopefully this post stays for others who are newer to Mathematica to learn from.

Answer (score 3):

For others struggling I figured it out. Just use Normal@Series when doing the expansion. Then you can use $/.e\rightarrow 1$ without issue.